# How to see CPU and memory usage for a program after running it

Tags: scripts, cpu, memory-usage

I wrote a shell script and run it with terminal. The script calls other programs and so has some child process.

How can I see **TOTAL** memory and CPU used for that script after running it ?

more generally : how can I see CPU and memory usage for a program after running it?

Comment: Does your initiating script run until all child processes have completed, or may they continue onward?

Comment: @MarkWilliams .they are complete after a short time and script finish,too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`time command` will give you the run time, with user/total/spu breakdown, which is the other factor you wanted.

Memory is trickier and you may need to run a parallel command to monitor that. Can you include commands in your script(s)?

Answer (score 0):

Actually If you can get PID of your script then you can use this command to see its CPU,memory utilization

```
ps -p <PID_Here> -o %cpu,%mem,cmd
```

Comment: after run script, the field for that in the process information terminated and doesn't show true data.

Comment: Its close.. I think I can fix it...